# What is body-content class in bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am doing [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bootstrap) but I dont get what **body-content** class does. I am aware of **container** and **container-fluid**. Can someone explain or point me to bootstrap documentation for this. Googling did not help me.

Comment: There is no `body-content` class in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Hi wait a minute. Then why is that there in that tutorial. Am I missing something? Just search for body-content in that page.

Comment: I don't know what turorial, probably it's useless :)

Comment: `body-content` just a user-defined class.

Comment: Man.. thats from MS :(  Thanks any way

Comment: Thank you, you are right.. thats a user defined one.

Comment: Wow, I definitely learned something new today!

Comment: Question for anyone who wishes to answer.. MS defined that to put padding on the 'body' of the website... what other way can we define the body exclude the navbar stuff?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Body-content is a CssClass located in /Content/Site.css (which is created by Visual Studio automatically) to move all the content on a site 50px down because of the nav-bar on the top of the site, which is exactly 50px high.

Answer (score 5):

Hira's answer might be true for some given templates, but, FYI, in some templates like the one I'm using for my project, .body-content is defined in site.css as:

```
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

(Which seems redundant and unnecessary when on the same element as bootstrap's .container). On the template I'm using, the site.css puts the 50px padding on the body element:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```